I am intializing PDA in anchor and getting the following error
transactionLogs: [
    'Program CYtc2hrkhfgH3CFP1VZNn4wm1voHL9JZjTndUc5Jiw8d invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: DepositeToken',
    'Program CYtc2hrkhfgH3CFP1VZNn4wm1voHL9JZjTndUc5Jiw8d consumed 3224 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program CYtc2hrkhfgH3CFP1VZNn4wm1voHL9JZjTndUc5Jiw8d failed: Access violation in stack frame 5 at address 0x200005ff8 of size 8'
  ],

i am using following Constraints
     #[account(
        init,
        payer = sender,

        space = 500,

        seeds = [b"ATA_HOLD".as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub liquidity_info: Account<'info, TestStructure>,


You might be putting too many typed accounts on the stack.
Some suggestions from previous answers,

Try Boxing your typed account, in your example

     #[account(
        init,
        payer = sender,
        space = 500,
        seeds = [b"ATA_HOLD".as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub liquidity_info: Box<Account<'info, TestStructure>>,


If possible try splitting large functions/ixs into smaller ones.

If possible try reducing the space you are allocating the PDA's.



pub struct TestStructure {
pub profit: u8,

}
This is inside my structure how can it be too much

This is more than enough. Try changing the space to 9. 8 for the anchor discriminator and 1 byte for the u8.

space ref: https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/space.html
